# LiquidHaskell: Trying to use assume keyword, but data type is not numeric

Tags: haskell, liquid-haskell

I'm trying to write some specifications for the `Data.Ratio` module. So far I have:

```
module spec Data.Ratio where

import GHC.Real

Data.Ratio.denominator :: GHC.Real.Integral a => r : GHC.Real.Ratio a -> {x:a | x > 0}
```

The code I'm verifying is:

```
{-@ die :: {v:String | false} -> a @-}
die msg = error msg

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = 3 % 5
  print $ denominator x
  if denominator x < 0
    then die "bad ending"
    else putStrLn "good ending"
```

The code is judged safe, because denominator never returns a negative value.

I found this strange because I could have just written `x <= 0` as a postcondition, which according to the documentation of the `Data.Ratio` module is impossible. Apparently Liquid Haskell does not compare my postcondition to the implementation of `denominator`.

My understanding is that since the function implementation was not checked, I'm better off using the assume keyword:

```
assume Data.Ratio.denominator :: GHC.Real.Integral a => r : GHC.Real.Ratio a -> {x:a | x > 0}
```

However, I then get:

```
Error: Bad Type Specification
 assumed type GHC.Real.denominator :: (Ratio a) -> {VV : a | VV > 0}
     Sort Error in Refinement: {VV : a_a2kc | VV > 0}
     Unbound Symbol a_a2kc
 Perhaps you meant: papp5, papp3, papp4, head, papp2, papp7, papp6, papp1, tail
  because
The sort a_a2kc is not numeric
```

My questions are

1. Shouldn't LH force me to use the `assume` keyword in this case if it clearly didn't verify the correctness of my refined type by comparing with the function implementation?
2. Am I right in thinking I should use the `assume` keyword?
3. How come `a` is suddenly not numeric? Wasn't it numeric when I didn't use `assume`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately by 'Numeric' it literally means 'Num' and not even subclasses thereof. We need to extend LH to support sub-classes in the form you describe above; I will create an issue for it, thanks for pointing out!

Now, if you specialize your type to, e.g. `Int` or `Integer` then LH properly throws the error:

```
import GHC.Real

{-@ assume denom :: r:GHC.Real.Ratio Int -> {x:Int | x >= 0} @-}
denom :: GHC.Real.Ratio Int -> Int 
denom = denominator

{-@ die :: {v:String | false} -> a @-}
die msg = error msg

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = 3 % 5
  print $ denom x
  if denom x <= 0
    then die "bad ending"
    else putStrLn "good ending"
```

http://goto.ucsd.edu:8090/index.html#?demo=permalink%2F1504739852_3583.hs

if you make the output type `x > 0` then it is safe again.

http://goto.ucsd.edu:8090/index.html#?demo=permalink%2F1504739907_3585.hs

Thanks again for pointing out the `Ratio` issue!